# How can I prove that the product of a sequence of a function and a function is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

If I have function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous on this interval and $(g_n)$ is a sequence of continuous functions such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}|g_n(x)|dx=0$, I want to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x_n)dx=0$.

I think the first step is to say that since $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, it follows that  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)g_n(x)|dx=0$. Then, using the Absolute Property, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g_n(x)dx\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)g_n(x)|dx=0$ and so the statement holds.

I think I am missing a huge step in the middle but I am not sure what that could be.

Comment: the expression "on this interval" doesn't make sense, as the interval is the domain of $f$, that is, you only need to say that $f$ is continuous. Now, about your question: you forget the absolute value signs in the LHS of your last inequality, it must be $\left|  \int_{a}^b f(x)g_n(x)dx\right|$. Also, observe that $|f(x)|\leqslant M$ for some $M>0$ for all $x$, therefore $|f(x)g_n(x)|\leqslant M|g_n(x)|$

Comment: Oh I mean on $[a,b]$. Sorry I thought that part would have been clear. If I fix what you said, would that be a good enough proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity I will give a complete proof of the statement. First you need to know, or prove, that

$$
\left| \int_{a}^b h(x)dx \right|\leqslant \int_{a}^b |h(x)|dx
$$

when the last integral is finite. Also, as $f$ is continuous and it domain is compact then the image of $f$ is also compact, this imply that the image of $f$ is bounded, say by a constant $M>0$, therefore

$$
0\leqslant \left| \int_{a}^b f(x)g_n(x) \right|\leqslant \int_{a}^b |f(x)g_n(x)| dx\leqslant M \int_{a}^b |g_n(x)|<\infty 
$$

for all $n$. As limits of real-valued sequences respect order relations, taking limits above you find that

$$
0\leqslant \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g_n(x)dx\right|\leqslant M\cdot 0=0\\
\therefore\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g_n(x)dx=0
$$

∎